# How do I redirect users from the registration page to Paypal?

Tags: users

Only users with a "Sign Up Code" are allowed to sign up to the website. If they provide a valid signup code, they will be directed to a sign up page where they can provide user information, and PayPal processing is used to process the fee. On completion of payment an account is created.

How can I redirect user to Paypal?
How can I check the payment is paid by user?
How can I create the account if the user paid?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  I would advise revising it into several specific smaller questions.

Comment: you changed the question completely !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

1. Add the [Paypal](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) payment method module; hook the login/register form to provide a different redirect page, or use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.
2. You can look at the generated transaction.
3. I would create the account anyway; set a flag, or something, for payed accounts.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is to use [hook_user($op)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6) implement it in your module, and work with `$op`.
I personally have done work like you want with that hook.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using Drupal commerce will be extra load(not sure).

> Custom Way:

- Over ride drupal registration form with your custom form
- submit handler of your custom form will keep all submit value in session

> How can I redirect user to Paypal?

- You can create a custom payment script
- commerce paypal module will be helpful to see the payment process.commerce paypal module has both off-site and on-site payment options.

How can I check the payment is paid by user?

- IPN is what paypal returns after a payment(success or failure).
- You can check IPN response to get the payment status.
  How can I create the account if the user paid?
- If successful payment is done create user from session values using [user_save()](http://codekarate.com/blog/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically) .